# Strongest muscle of Human Body

Tags: muscles

Which is the strongest muscle of human body ?

Confusion b/w **Masseter muscle** (Muscle of Jaw) and **Tongue** and **Muscle of Heart** and **Muscle of Uterus**.

Comment: What do you mean by strongest? The one that can apply the highest force or the one that has the greatest endurance?

Comment: First internet search result gives you everything you may be interested in, and looks reasonably reliable: http://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/muscles.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be interested in **[THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle#The_.22strongest.22_human_muscle)** Wikipedia article. It really depends on how you define "strongest" (Newtons, Wattage, Newtons per Kilogram, etc.). Here are a few relevant excerpts from the article:

> In ordinary parlance, muscular "strength" usually refers to **the ability to exert a force on an external object**—for example, lifting a weight. By this definition, the **masseter** or jaw muscle is the strongest. The 1992 Guinness Book of Records records the achievement of a bite strength of 4,337 N (975 lbf) for 2 seconds. What distinguishes the masseter is not anything special about the muscle itself, but its advantage in working against a much shorter lever arm than other muscles.
>
> If "strength" refers to **the force exerted by the muscle itself**, e.g., on the place where it inserts into a bone, then the strongest muscles are those with the largest cross-sectional area. This is because the tension exerted by an individual skeletal muscle fiber does not vary much. Each fiber can exert a force on the order of 0.3 micronewton. By this definition, the strongest muscle of the body is usually said to be the **quadriceps femoris** or the **gluteus maximus**.
>
> The **heart** has a claim to being **the muscle that performs the largest quantity of physical work in the course of a lifetime**. Estimates of the power output of the human heart range from 1 to 5 watts.[14] This is much less than the maximum power output of other muscles; for example, the quadriceps can produce over 100 watts, but only for a few minutes. The heart does its work continuously over an entire lifetime without pause, and thus does "outwork" other muscles. An output of one watt continuously for eighty years yields a total work output of two and a half gigajoules.